# Weird ComboBox behavior when using ComboBox.Text to select an item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Let's make an example.

```xaml
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbTest" IsEditable="False">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="ab"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="abc 1"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="abc"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="8 (1)"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="8 (2)"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="100"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
 </ComboBox>
```

Then try each line in code:

```
cmbTest.Text = "7";      //Correctly selected, .SelectedIndex = 0
cmbTest.Text = "ab";     //Correctly selected, .SelectedIndex = 1
cmbTest.Text = "abc 1";  //Correctly selected, .SelectedIndex = 2
cmbTest.Text = "abc";    //Nothing selected,   .SelectedIndex = -1
cmbTest.Text = "8 (1)";  //Correctly selected, .SelectedIndex = 4
cmbTest.Text = "8 (2)";  //Correctly selected, .SelectedIndex = 5
cmbTest.Text = "9";      //Correctly selected, .SelectedIndex = 6
cmbTest.Text = "8";      //Nothing selected,   .SelectedIndex = -1
cmbTest.Text = "100";    //Correctly selected, .SelectedIndex = 8
cmbTest.Text = "10";     //Nothing selected,   .SelectedIndex = -1
cmbTest.Text = "1";      //Nothing selected,   .SelectedIndex = -1
```

Any item where it starts as a substring of any previous item isn't properly selected.

It's even dangerous when `IsEditable=True`. The item is properly shown/selected but returns -1 as its `SelectedIndex` (same as above).

Aside from iterating and using `SelectedIndex` to select an item (what I did to fix this), is there a way to fix this behavior? Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the bad UX configuration of the Default ComboBox.

I don't know if what you want is right, but I solved it like this.

```
// override default ComboBox
// MyComboBox.cs
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private TextBox PART_EditableTextBox;
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        if (PART_EditableTextBox != null)
            PART_EditableTextBox.LostFocus -= PART_EditableTextBox_LostFocus;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

#warning it works only when 'IsEditable' property is 'True'
        FrameworkElement root = GetVisualChild(0) as FrameworkElement;
        PART_EditableTextBox = (TextBox)root.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox");
        PART_EditableTextBox.LostFocus += PART_EditableTextBox_LostFocus;
    }
    private void PART_EditableTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PART_EditableTextBox == null) return;
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DisplayMemberPath))
                if (SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem)
                    PART_EditableTextBox.Text = comboBoxItem.Content?.ToString();
                else
                    PART_EditableTextBox.Text = SelectedItem?.ToString();
            else PART_EditableTextBox.Text = SelectedItem?.GetType().GetProperty(DisplayMemberPath)?.GetValue(SelectedItem)?.ToString();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

The core of the idea is to give appropriate feedback to the user (when the 'LostFocus' event fires) when the user thinks they've made a selection.

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyComboBox IsEditable="True">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="7"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ab"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="abc 1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="abc"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="8 (1)"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="8 (2)"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="9"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="8"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="100"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="10"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
    </local:MyComboBox>
    <TextBox/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this prevents selection of the problematic items via editing/typing. The only solution I guess is to always sort the items.